# How to pass an array variable if it is defined as `ref` param in the c# code

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I am calling the following function defined in a C# dll:

```
public class Master:IMaster
{
...
public void WriteSingleCoils(ushort id, byte unit, ushort startAddress, bool OnOff, ref byte[] result)
{
byte[] data;
data = CreateWriteHeader(id, unit, startAddress, 1, 1, fctWriteSingleCoil);
if (OnOff == true) data[10] = 255;
else data[10] = 0;
result = WriteSyncData(data, id);
}
...
}
```

from the following c++ application code:

```
pIMast = new IMasterPtr(__uuidof(Master));
unsigned char* ptr = 0;
pIMast->WriteSingleCoils(1, 0, 144, true, (SAFEARRAY**)ptr);
```

The dll as well as the application are compiling fine. But the application is not working properly. I am only concerned with the last parameter `ref byte[] result`. Am i calling it correctly? How to pass an array variable if it is defined as `ref` param in the c# code?

Comment: I would say, that the line `pIMast->WriteSingleCoils(1, 0, 144, true, (SAFEARRAY**)ptr);` is not correct. Since you want to change the pointer, there should be`&ptr`. *(perhaps `(SAFEARRAY**)&ptr`, but I¨m not so sure with the type/definition of `SAFEARRAY`)*

Answer (score 0):

I would try and pass the PTR in as a reference in C++

```
pIMast = new IMasterPtr(__uuidof(Master));     
unsigned char* ptr = 0; 
pIMast->WriteSingleCoils(1, 0, 144, true, (SAFEARRAY**)&ptr);
```

> https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbclx01/cplr233.htm

Hope this helps

Comment: May be worth mentioning it because this seems like the obvious answer